# Can't run golang mobile package given examples

Tags: go

I was trying to test golang mobile package given examples(`https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/example`), but unfortunatly i get some errors:

```
C:\Users\D\Documents\gocode\src\golang.org\x\mobile\example\flappy>go run main.go
# golang.org/x/mobile/gl
..\..\gl\gl.go:1683: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1695: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1707: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1719: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1731: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1743: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1755: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1773: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1783: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1794: undefined: context3
..\..\gl\gl.go:1794: too many errors
```

For mobile package install, i wrote only `go get golang.org/x/mobile` command, i am using `go1.6.2 windows/amd64` go version.

Comment: A comment for future cases (not only for mobile). If there are multiple files in your Go project, go run won't work, use go build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate apk for testing, you should run command below:

```
gomobile build -target=android golang.org/x/mobile/example/flappy
```

more info can be found [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile)